# Collating all the http response inside a common function using $q in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-q

I am trying to use the `$q` service inside my controller. I have multiple environment which I need to hit and collect the data and consolidate the data and then put inside the scope. I have the below code.

```
     var results=[];
     for(var environment in  $rootScope.envs){
       $http.get(callService.getDomainUrl()+'/'+$rootScope.envs[environment]+ '/hosts.json').success(function(data){
              results.push(data)
          })
      }

      $q.all(results).then(function(){
          console.log(results);
      })
```

However, I am not sure if this is the right approach and also I need to map the result into an object of the below type:

```
results:{
  env1: { // result data for env1},
  env2: { // result data for env2},
  env3: { // result data for env3},
}
```

How to resolve the promise and consolidate the data in the above format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to @SlavaUtesinov answer.
You should not to create new promises with `$q.defer`, just use `$http.get` return.

You'll get something like this:

```
  $q.all(Object.keys($rootScope.envs).map(request)).then(function(res){
    var results = {};
    for (var env in res) {
      results[env] = res[env].data;
    }
    console.log(results);
  }, function(err){
    console.error(err);
  });

  function request(env) {
    return $http.get(callService.getDomainUrl()+'/'+$rootScope.envs[env]+ '/hosts.json');
  }
```

Anyway, `$q.all` combine array/hash of promises into a single promise.
So, you should collect promises before call it.

Comment: The above code works absolutely fine. However, the results object contains all the response from four environments. I need to map the response of each envrionement against its name. How can we get this done in the format of response={[{env1: {env2-res object}}, {env2: {env2-res object}, {env3: {env3-res object}}]}

Comment: If you pass hash object with promises to `$q.all` original keys will be saved in the result. You should pass `{'env1': request('env1'), env2: request('env2')}` hash to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MnJ7wBxqxJ6gHUOYghfe?p=preview)(look at log). I simulate $http.get request by means of `setTimeout` function.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. If there is an error, what is the best way to handle the error condition for any of the environment?

Comment: Also the results object now contains the data and not with the key mapped to the environment name. I want the output to be in { env1: {data1}, env2: {data2}, env3: {data3}, env4:{data4}}

Comment: I correct my answer - shifted `var prom = $q.defer();promises.push(prom);`. And can you write what you fetch at your console: `console.log(results);`

Comment: And I added code for error processing, please look at new code!

Comment: This is an antipattern. You can use `$http.get` promise w/o create new one.

Comment: when I console the log, I am getting the data for only one call. I am able to see all the calls being made but I am seeing only one value in the console. The rest three result data is not populated in the `results` object. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Yes I made one mistake - I added to array of `promises` not actual promises, but the result of $q.defer(), that was wrong, please, look at example.